# Meteorjs react universe:i18n

Tags: reactjs, meteor

**I need to implement `universe:i18n` in meteor and react i tried a lot but it didn’t work ,
so i need a simple example or source code explain how to configure `universe:i18n` with the project .
Please help me**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add code that "didn't work" because this is the foundation of writing a sophisticated answer. Please also read the help me section on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation?

https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-i18n#creating-a-react-component